# Media library corrupted after upgrading to 4.9.6

Tags: media-library, upgrade

I just upgraded WP to 4.9.6. My WP installation is on Windows 10 in a XAMPP installation, running as a virtual server on my laptop.

I migrated this site from a remote LAMP server, with mostly identical results.

Here's a screen shot of the media library "before":

[image]

Here's a screen shot of the media library "after" upgrade:

[image]

I also upgraded to 4.9.6 on the remote server, which continues to work normally.

Any suggestions?

---

After investigating online, I learned that the gui field of the wp-posts table contains urls. I noticed that in my table, the urls pointed to a previous incarnation of this WP site. I did a bulk sql update so that the string values in the GUI field of the wp_posts table reflect the correct, current virtual server url on my localhost.

The basic sql statement to update a whole bunch of sub-strings is like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'articles/updates/', 'articles/news/')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%articles/updates/%'
```

But that operation didn't solve the problem. However, on the media library page I noticed two little icons, one looks like a "list" icon, the other a "grid" icon. When I click on the "list" icon, all my media files show:

[image]

But when I click back to the "grid" display icon, same problem, "No media files found."

[image]

My ID columns in wp_posts and wp_postmeta were not set to auto increment (AI). Once I set these columns to AI from phpMyAdmin, the thumbnail grid immediately worked.

Comment: do you have debugging enabled? any php errors? any js errors in the console?

Comment: Does the admin footer of that page show? If it doesn’t the page did fatally error, check logs as mentioned above. Try disabling plugins one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: Good question. The admin footer does show. The document loaded. I'll investigate the other suggestions, thx. I just deactivated the first plugin, Advanced Custom Fields PRO, and now it says "No media files found." Also, the blank gray "thumbnail" disappeared. Weird.

Comment: Now that I look at the GUID values in the wp_posts table, I see a lot of url values pointing to a previous the url of a previous website. Going to have to do a bulk UPDATE operation. I'll report back.

Comment: My ID columns in wp_posts and wp_postmeta were not set to auto increment (AI). One I set these columns to AI from phpMyAdmin, the thumbnail grid immediately worked.

Comment: In general GUID should not be touched, it is a globally unique id, and as long as it unique there is no reason to change it. It is also not a url, it is a random value that looks like url. If you have any code that uses it for anything else, you should get rid of it.

Comment: The GUID values contained incorrect url strings, so they absolutely had to be updated. Updating these values to reflect the correct website url (e.g.: "http://localhost/site") was a relatively easy and correct procedure. In fact, I should keep going and globally replace the old url string with the new, present one in every table.